# Как сделать запрос jsonp в Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ulogin

Читал тут http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Пробовал так

```
var express = require('express');

var user = express();
user.get("http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=test&host=test", function (req, res) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
});
```

На PHP это выглядит так

```
$s = file_get_contents('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=' . $token . '&host=' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

На angular как то так

```
 var host = $location.host();
            var url = "//ulogin.ru/token.php?host=" +
                encodeURIComponent(location.toString()) + "&token=" + this.token + "&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
            if (this.busy)
                return;
            this.busy = true;
            $http.jsonp(url).
            success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //console.log(data);
                this.user = data;
                this.busy = false;
                this.login();
                $('#myModalAuth').modal('hide');
                if (typeof callback == 'function') {
                    callback();
                }
            }.bind(this)).
            error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получить ответ от Ulogin можно так

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token=test&host=test', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите по запросу в express вернуть результат авторизации на другом ресурсе, вам видимо стоит просто воспользоваться редиректом.

```
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/url', function (req, res) {
   //Тут вам доступны req.query для чтения GET
   res.redirect(301, 'http://ulogin.ru/token.php?token='+req.query.token);
   //Просто ответить в JSONP
   res.jsonp({data: 'somedata;});
});
```

Документацию можно [почитать тут](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.jsonp)
И что-то не вижу у вас jsoncallback, в случае JSONP он обязателен. Возможно вы делаете просто GET запрос?

Comment: а url куда писать? вроде так же пробовал

Comment: Дополнил ответ новыми комментариями

Comment: На стороне сервера не обязательно писать callback, не будет ошибки access denied, вот если бы вы в ответ еще HTTP_HOST дописали, а то ищу сейчас

Comment: HTTP_HOST по моему константа просто будет